consumption, income and utility
Question Description:
Consider an economy populated by a large number of Farmers (F) and Computer Scientists (CS). Each person divides his 24-hour day into labour and leisure. If a Farmer decides to work L hours, he will produce L loaves of Bread (B). If a Computer Scientist decides to work for L hours, he will produce L computer Games (G). Assume the price of Bread is one dollar and the price of Game is p dollar. All people have identical utility function  = 24 −  + 3√ + 2√, where 24 −  is time devoted to leisure.
(i)For a Farmer, find his consumption of Bread, consumption of Games, how many hours he will decide to work, and his income as a function of p.
(ii) Assume 75% population are Farmers and 25% are Computer Scientists. Find p.
My Attempt
For (i), I suppose that every person (both farmers and computer scientists) would try to maximize their utility, so we definitely have to take the derivative of such a function. However, I could not make any further progress (my educational guess is that we should somewhat express everything in terms of L and assume that the supply for each commodity is infinite).
For (ii), I am clueless about how can the price be connected to the proportions of farmers and computer scientists.
Thank you in advance!
